# AsyncTask : Do not hide keyboard while dismissing ProgressDialog in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-softkeyboard, progressdialog

When I use AsyncTask :

```
class GetStreetName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_loading));
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
         // backGround task
    }
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        if (result!=null) {
               ....
             progressDialog.dismiss();
            enterStreetEditText.requestFocus();
       }
    }
```

when I do like this, the keyboard is hiden when the dialog is dismisses in `onPostExecute`. How can I prevent this and keep showing the keyboard while the dialog is dismissing ? 
When I do not using the ProgressDialog, the problem is not occurs.

Comment: Please try to add `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` when declaring enterStreetEditText in your XML

Answer (score 0):

It may help you:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    if (result!=null) {
           ....
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         enterStreetEditText.setFocusable(true);
         enterStreetEditText.requestFocus();
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.showSoftInput(enterStreetEditText , 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but that is didn't work for me. Besides, I do not need to reopen the keyboard, I need it NOT TO BE CLOSED.